# Freelancing in Europe

Tags: germany, taxes, netherlands, freelance

I just got a freelancing job in the Netherlands for 6 months and I really want to know what should I do to make sure I pay taxes and do this employment legally.

I currently live in Germany as a student and I hold German citizenship. The freelance job requires me to go only once a month for 4-5 days to the office.

The company is a tech company and I would be doing some tech + marketing job.

Do I need to pay taxes in Germany or in the Netherlands? Can I start working right now, or do I need to do some paperwork? I will be paid 32 per hour 8 hours a week. Is that enough to cover my expenses as a freelancer? How much tax would I have to pay?

If I registering in Germany, what are the steps to start freelancing right away?

If anybody can guide me, tell me what are my best options or any info at all it would be highly appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information about my situation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you contacted your employer for advice?

Comment: I just did. I wanted to see if there is any info out here, So I can have an idea of what to do

Comment: Your question is far too broad. You need to do some research first eg https://www.iamsterdam.com/en/work/start-a-business/going-freelance and if you still need help you should edit your question to be more specific. Your university might/should be able to help too

Comment: There is also https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/ where someone might have relevant experience